# How to disable dropdown suggestion in xCode13

Tags: xcode

When recording UI test I see inline dropdown suggestions - I can remove one by double tap on it, but I wonder if there is a way to disable them once and for all?

[image]

Comment: Cool! How do I _enable_ that?

Comment: I need to double click the selection in order to edit  it - you definitely don't want this :)

Comment: I'm totally not seeing that interface.

Comment: Is this only after recording a UI test? If so, it's not new.

Comment: Yes, looks like its only on my recording code - I will edit my question - 10x. Still can I remove it?